# iOS 5 storyboards - table views within view controllers

Tags: ios, storyboard

Hello I am trying to create an app with storyboards that uses a table view embedded withing a regular view. However, I am unable to hook up the delegate, datasource, and outlet from the view controller to the table view. Is this not supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `UITableView` as a subview of an existing view in a storyboard, hook up its `dataSource` and `delegate` outlets, and connect an outlet to the table view.  There's nothing special about it.  Which part are you having trouble with?

Here's a video of the process: http://youtu.be/y95FfxJrX2U